Quasi-experimental design and potential endogeneity issue in a linear model
I have a practical question about endogeneity. Assume a linear model, where the dependent variable is deforestation (mapped from satellite imagery) and one of the independent variables is cloud cover. Since cloud cover affects our capability to observe the actual deforestation at a given point in time (but deforestation does not affect cloud cover), I wonder if there is still an endogeneity problem here?
For context (if relevant), I am ultimately interested in using cloud cover (panel data) to create some variability across my sample units (e.g., municipalities) in order to estimate the impact of a policy to reduce deforestation that was implemented in a given year and affects all my sample units (i.e., no temporal variability, only spatial variability across the municipalities).

Can you clarify why you are trying to "create variability"? (and how?). Variability is noise, something usually one wants to reduce...
